# $uibModal tries force execute submit in my form

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog, created with ui.bootstrap. When I'm performing some code with `$uibModal` or `$uibModalInstance`, inside of controller of this modal, AngularJS try to call submit method of my `<form>` from dialog. Also, my `<form>` hasn't a `submit` attribute, but it has a `ng-submit` attribute.

Here is a part of my modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <form name="newActionForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{ 'action.labelNewAction' | translate }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label site-form-label">{{ 'common.labelName' | translate }}:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 input-group padding_right_left_15" ng-class=" newActionForm.name.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error' ">
                    <input required ng-maxlength="160" ng-change="vm.test()" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.newAction.name"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-show="newActionForm.name.$error.required" tooltip="{{'formValidationRequired' | translate}}"></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-show="newActionForm.name.$error.maxlength" tooltip="{{'formValidationNameTooLong' | translate}}"></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-show="newActionForm.name.$valid"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button ng-disabled="newActionForm.$invalid"  class="btn btn_kassir" ng-click="vm.addAction()">{{ 'common.labelButtonAdd' | translate }}</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">{{ 'common.labelButtonClose' | translate }}</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and modal contoller with two functions, that tries to perform sumbit on my form:

```
angular
        .module('newActionDialog')
        .controller('NewActionDialogController',
            [ '$scope', '$stateParams', '$uibModalInstance', 'Requester', '$uibModal', '$filter', '$translate', 'alertService', NewActionDialogController]);

    function NewActionDialogController($scope, $stateParams, $uibModalInstance,  Requester, $uibModal, $filter, $translate, alertService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.showSelectHall=function(){
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl:  'app/repertoire/listHalls.html',
                controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
                    this.select = function (hallConfig) {
                        $uibModalInstance.close(hallConfig);
                    };
                },
                controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            }).result.then(function (hallConfig) {
                vm.newAction.defaultHallConfiguration=hallConfig;
            });
        };

        ......       

        vm.close=function(){
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have to create the submit function inside the modal scope the assign the function as ng-submit="someFunction()" then it will work

Comment: @Ahmer my problem is not that I can't perform submit operation, it's that angular tries perform submit without my order.

Comment: got it create one hide input tag with type submit it will submit your form when you press enter

Comment: @Ahmer This workaround isn't good for me, as when I'm trying perform `$uibModalInstance.close()`, modal doesn't closing because of `required` fields, that can be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been solved and it was occuring because of the `$uibModal.open()` method creates a modal with a `<buttons type="submit">` by default. So, after `$uibModal.open()`  `<button>` transformed to `<button type="submit>`. Solution is add to all buttons `type="button"`, except real submit button, of course.

Comment: Saved me hours! Thank you